# Extract Magento Module into Separate Repository

Tags: git, magento

We have a git repository that currently holds a working Magento site. The repository holds all the core Magento files as well as some custom and community modules. What I would like to do is take some of the custom modules and move them out into their own repositories.

Unfortunately, as those of you familiar with Magentos' directory structure will know, a module in Magento is not fully self contained in a single directory, instead the files are spread across multiple directories such as `app/code/local/{namespace}/{module}/`, `app/design/frontend/base/{namespace}_{module}/` etc. What I would like to achieve is a repository that holds all the files for just one module, in the same directory structure that they currently have. At this point I'll be able to create distributable archives that simply need extracting into a Magento site directory (though I will likely use modman in my own projects, to maintain separation).

I can think of two simple approaches:

1. Clone the repository, delete all files not related to the module in
   question and change the  origin remote to a new blank repository.
2. Initialise a new repository in a blank folder and copy / paste the
   files into the correct directory hierarchy. Commit them.

The downside to both of these approaches is that I would lose all commit history on the files, which would be a shame. I've done a bit of research on how I might be able to retain this, doing a sub-tree split seemed promising, but proved beyond my ability with the fact the files weren't all in the same directory. Has anyone got experience in doing this kind of thing?

Comment: This looks like a candidate for `git filter-branch`, which is quite some monster...

Answer (score 1):

I found what you want (hopefully):
https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subpath-out-into-a-new-repo

OLD ANSWER:
Have a look on: https://github.com/colinmollenhour/modman I prefer it.

But there is a second thing I didn't try yet:
https://github.com/jreinke/modgit

Comment: You somewhat missed the point. I even mentioned I intend to use modman.

Comment: I believe the answer may lay with filter-branch, unfortunately though I've been unable to get it working on more than a single sub-directory path.

Comment: damn, I fear that :( no idea on this. Time for a git expert :)